# Cannot connect to a fresh brew install of mysql from a client on the same host

Tags: mac, mysql, homebrew

I just did a fresh install of mysql on a mac using brew.

`brew install mysql`

We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
mysql -u root

To restart mysql after an upgrade:
brew services restart mysql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql

It is running...
`ps -ef | grep mysql`

501 43364     1   0  8:35PM ??         0:00.02 /bin/sh /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql
501 43467 43364   0  8:35PM ??         0:04.08 /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=Marcs-MacBook-Pro-2.local.err --pid-file=Marcs-MacBook-Pro-2.local.pid

**ISSUE #1**
The post install instructions say:
"To connect run:
mysql -u root"

That does not work:
% mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

So, in order to be able to login as ANY user I have to run the mysql_secure_installation to set a password for the root user. I do that and I'm then able to login from a terminal.
However, I want to use the SequalPro client or mysqlworkbench or whatever...

**ISSUE #2**
When attempting to connect with a client I get the following:

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.
> Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).
> MySQL said: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 0x0002): tried: '/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so' (no such file)

I have uninstalled and reinstalled and I get the exact same error each time.

Obviously I need some help with the proper incantation to get this working correctly.

thanks